# Reorder List of Lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of lists. I need the elements inside reordered so that the new list of lists is a list of all the first elements, then a list of all the second elements, etc.
It should look like this:

```
Input
[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]


Output
[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3]]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are they all of size 3? You can use the `transpose` function.

Comment: It would courteous to accept an answer

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you want `transpose`, for which you need to import `Data.List`.

`transpose` will take the first elements of the lists that have them and put them in the first list in the right order, then the second elements of the lists that have them and put them in the second list in the right order, and so on.

For example,

```
> transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
[[1,4,6],[2,5],[3]]

> transpose [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[1,2,4],[3,5],[6]]
```

Answer (score 4):

In general when confronted with such issues :

- Determine the type of the function you need, here `[[a]] -> [[a]]`
- Search Hoogle http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Guess first result in your case ? `transpose` of course.

*NB : You should accept answer from user3217013 - I wrote this because I can't edit yet*